# Get Time rounded to nearest 5 minute interval and convert only the minutes to a String

Tags: java

I am looking at this example

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1385577373517L, DateTimeZone.UTC);
// Prints 2013-11-27T18:36:13.517Z
System.out.println(dt);

// Prints 2013-11-27T18:36:00.000Z (Floor rounded to a minute)
System.out.println(dt.minuteOfDay().roundFloorCopy());

// Prints 2013-11-27T18:30:00.000Z (Rounded to custom minute Window)
int windowMinutes = 10;
System.out.println(
    dt.withMinuteOfHour((dt.getMinuteOfHour() / windowMinutes) * windowMinutes)
        .minuteOfDay().roundFloorCopy()
    );
```

What I want to do is extract just the minute which is rounded to nearest 10 minute interval (say just "30") and convert it to a string so that i can passit on as an input at some other place.

Comment: The nearest 10 minute interval* of 36 is 40. Do you want the nearest 10-minute interval* that is less than or equal to the actual minutes?

Comment: either 30 or 40 is ok with me. 40 would be nice actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you can fine tune your rounding rules around:

```
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(1385577373517L, DateTimeZone.UTC);
    // Prints 2013-11-27T18:36:13.517Z
    System.out.println(dt);

    // Prints 2013-11-27T18:36:00.000Z (Floor rounded to a minute)
    System.out.println(dt.minuteOfDay().roundFloorCopy());

    // Prints 2013-11-27T18:30:00.000Z (Rounded to custom minute Window)
    int windowMinutes = 10;
    System.out.println(
        dt.withMinuteOfHour((dt.getMinuteOfHour() / windowMinutes) * windowMinutes).minuteOfDay().roundFloorCopy()
    );        

    SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("m");
    String minute = DATE_FORMAT.format(dt.toDate());

    String minString = "" + ((int)Math.round(Integer.parseInt(minute)/10)) * 10;

    System.out.println("Result: " +  minString);
```